# Why is equalTo number only finding strings in FireBase?

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am trying a simple query:

```
@Input('jobId') id: number;

comments: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

this.comments = this.af.database.list('comments/jobComments', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'jobId',
    equalTo: <number>this.id
  }
}).map((array) => array.reverse()) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

and I have a few jobId's that are strings, and the rest are numbers. I'm going to make them all numbers soon. But for some reason this is only returning the results whose jobId is formatted as a string, and not returning anyone whose jobId is an integer.

The above code is only returning comments if their jobId looks like this in FireBase:

```
jobId: "1"
```

but not this:

```
jobId: 1
```

Comment: Try using orderByChild in place of equalTo if you want to compare with other types. Example:  query.orderByChild("primary_id").equalTo(1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<number>` is a TypeScript cast. It's static and simply tells TypeScript that the value is a `number`.

At runtime, that counts for nothing. If `this.id` contains a string, the value passed to `equalTo` is going to be a string - *not* a number - and it will only match `"1"` in Firebase.

If you want to ensure the value assigned to `equalTo` is a number, you could do something like this:

```ts
query: {
  orderByChild: 'jobId',
  equalTo: Number.parseInt(this.id, 10)
}
```

Comment: I get an error Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. this.id actually is a number.

Comment: Then somewhere, at runtime, it must actually have a string assigned to it. If Firebase is only matching `"1"` that's what the value is. You can either change it to `Number.parseInt(this.id as any, 10)` or can try to find where and why it's being set to a string at runtime.

Comment: I also have it writing to FireBase as a string, not just searching. But it's a number I swear

Comment: That last comment did it! Number.parseInt(this.id as any, 10)